# Client not able to send message to server

Tags: c, linux, sockets, client, server

I am new to socket programming in C. 
Am trying to create a server that has the ability to connect to multiple clients. However,

1. My message doesn't get printed on the server end. Which means the code doesn't stop at the prompt "What do you want to send?"
2. 2nd message on wards client doesn't respond to switch (choice)
   my Server.c looks like

**EDIT 1** I have edited the code that lets client send the message . However, server side stops at "error on ACCEPT: bad file descriptor" which I am unable to resolve.

**EDIT 2** My client is sending second message onwards too,but my server doesn't receive it and print it out, even though the error on Accept is gone.

```
-----
listen(sockfd,5);
clilen = sizeof(cli_add);
int pid;

while(1){
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_add, &clilen);
    if (newsockfd < 0){
        error ("Error on accept");
        exit(1);
    }

    pid=fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
                error("ERROR in new process creation");
                exit(1);
        }
    if (pid==0){
            close(sockfd);
            //read the buffer from socket    
            bzero(buffer, 256);
            n = read(newsockfd, buffer,255);
            if (n<0){
                error("Error reading");
                exit(1);
            }  
            printf("The message : %s", buffer);

        -----
            bzero(buffer,256);
            n=write(newsockfd,tmparray,strlen(tmparray));
            if (n<0)
                 error("oops! can't write");

            exit(0);
        }else{
            close(newsockfd);
        }
}
```

and client.c is

```
    int choice;
    while(1){
    printf("what to do?\n1.Send\n2.Exit\n");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    switch(choice){
        case 1:
        {
            bzero(buffer, 256);
            printf("What do you want to send? ");
            fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
            getchar();
            n=write(sockfd,buffer,255);
            if (n<0)
                error("oops! can't write");


            bzero(buffer,256);
            n= read(sockfd, buffer, 255);
            if (n<0)
                error("OOPS! can't read");
            printf("Received message : %s\n", buffer );
            break;

        }
        case 2:{
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but [`accept`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/accept.html) *modifies* the address-length argument, so you can't simply set it once outside the loop, you have to set it every time before calling `accept`.

Comment: After `scanf` there is a leftover newline in `stdin`. `gets` reads it and an empty message gets sent.

Comment: Thank you, for the help. The final code that did work solve problems is edit 3